# CPU Spike 150% on postgresql Google Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql-performance, cpu

I get random spikes running to 150% and it settles down in 2 mins
We have a postgres 9.6 database with 2TB data. Running on 48 cores and 180GB Ram

1. I have checked database logs,
2. I have set up cron job to run every min on pg_stats to capture any query running more than 2 sec ..
3. Checked google query insights

During these spikes I don't see any locks, just frequent queries getting affected (normal execution = 25mili, 45mils during spike.. )

I run this query every min via cron

```
SELECT (now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start)::text AS duration
       , concat('state : ', state)::text as state, usename, 'S' as action_step, 'U' as action
      , query
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE  query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%' 
and usename NOT ILIKE '%cloudsqladmin%' 
AND (now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start) > interval '2 seconds'
and state ='active' ;
```

Question: is there anything else to check or see for what could be causing these spikes?

Comment: Are the spikes causing problems? 150% of one core -- ie 1.5 cores fully utilized?

Comment: yes, for those couple of minutes the system gets very slow. also its 150% of all cores.. we go extra on our exisitng capacity